# Ho to compile deeplearning4j pretrained models into java bytecodes?

Tags: compilation, java-bytecode-asm, dl4j

**Why ask:**

I have trained a multi-layer network to recognize some specific soundwaves. It worked perfectly well, and costed only ~1ms to work. However, when I tried to migrate it to Android, I found to my astonishment that the apk is over 1GB. I checked my model and found that it was merely 50kb.I want to turn this model into java code that works without DL4J.I don’t care performance loss since the soundwave lengths 10secs each, and I have 10secs to waste.

**What have I tried & result:**

1. reduce the maven dependency into deeplearning4j-nn.(1GB->150MB).
2. cut the javacpp native libraries(150MB->100MB).
3. try to make a reduced C++ library(I can't. C++ is beyond me).

**What I want:**

I want it to be smaller than 1M.

**What would be helpful:**

1. agibsonccc mentioned that "years back" there was an util for this. I'd appreciate if somebody can simply provide me with the git version(or a clone would be even better).
2. Though I have searched through Github and found nothing, there can be some that I have missed. If there are any related projects, even unstable ones and abandoned ones, please inform me.
3. some other ways.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude dependencies you're not using? https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies

Comment: To get something smaller than 1 MB, you're probably going to need to look at something like TVM: http://bytedeco.org/news/2020/12/12/deploy-models-with-javacpp-and-tvm/

Comment: sorry,@Holger ,I did mis-spell it.

Comment: @Samuel Audet Yes I have but I can't get it small enough =.=

Comment: @Samuel Audet I am really interested this!But I don't fully understand that how can I put dl4j models into TVM.Can you tell me something more about it?Thanks!

Comment: TVM doesn't support DL4J models. You'll need to get it into one of those formats: https://tvm.apache.org/docs/how_to/compile_models/index.html